# Show Store Stock against each Products

Tags: magento2, product, multistore, catalog, store-view

> need to show, store wise qty.

```
> karama 01 19 left 
> karama 02 10 left
```

[image: need to show, store wise qty]

there is two stores and qty mentioned
[image: there is two stores and qty mentioned]

Comment: Do you have any definition on the DB or elsewhere on how to make the relationship between those two products?

Comment: is your question only related to simple product, configurable or any type? can you add details if possible?

Comment: correct me if i am wrong. the product are simple product. i added source and i added stock.